# How to generate / serve a nuxt.js application with pre-rendered body

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'm trying to serve a pre-rendered application trough 'nuxt generate' and SSR as well. But with both methods nuxt generates only the head and javascript files in the source code.

How to serve a pre-rendered body source code?

I tried a lot of options. Already have mode on universal. After googling a while I cant find out what I'm doing wrong

this is my nuxt.config.js

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  rootDir: resolve(__dirname, '../..'),
  srcDir: __dirname,
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],
  loadingIndicator: false,
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  },
  generate: {
    dir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  manifest: {
    name: 'Testpage',
    description: 'Rendering test'
  },
  css: [
    { src: '~css/app.scss', lang: 'scss' }
  ]
}
```

this is the output after running 'nuxt generate'

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-n-head="lang">
  <head data-n-head="">
    <title data-n-head="true">Demo</title><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="charset" charset="utf-8"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,minimal-ui"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="mobile-web-app-capable" name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="apple-mobile-web-app-title" name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Nuxt7"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="description" name="description" content="Demo"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#007aff"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="og:type" name="og:type" property="og:type" content="website"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="og:title" name="og:title" property="og:title" content="Nuxt7"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="og:site_name" name="og:site_name" property="og:site_name" content="Nuxt7"><meta data-n-head="true" data-hid="og:description" name="og:description" property="og:description" content="Demo"><link data-n-head="true" rel="manifest" href="/_nuxt/manifest.1899f21a.json"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/4ae4226aa74ce46f6364.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/c1f1f89e5e4d81cd2ad8.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/1b7d9c2f4e17f4e9ebab.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/b435d311b336c9debba1.css" as="style"><link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/f5b8c28e8c4940cefa89.js" as="script">
  <link href="/_nuxt/b435d311b336c9debba1.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body data-n-head="">
    <div id="__nuxt"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/4ae4226aa74ce46f6364.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/c1f1f89e5e4d81cd2ad8.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/1b7d9c2f4e17f4e9ebab.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_nuxt/f5b8c28e8c4940cefa89.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

How can I generate the body output of the page aswell?

Comment: Do you have an Index.vue in your pages folder?